# Vectorizing a (recursive) function F#

Tags: function, recursion, f#

New to F#, and as my main tool is R, I am finding these "lower level" languages a bit challanging. I am trying to write a recursive function (Cox-de Boor) that given an input vector x (array or similar) returns a vector of same length. Other parameters are int,int and float[]. So far I have only managed to do it for a single x. I`m pretty sure my code is stupid, so any tip will be appreciated.

```
let rec basis (x:float) degree i (knots:float[]) =
let B=
    match degree=0 with
    |true -> if (x>=knots.[i-1] && x < knots.[i]) then 1.0 else  0.0
    |false -> let Alpha1 =
                match ((knots.[degree+i-1] - knots.[i-1])=0.0) with
                |true -> 0.0
                |false -> (x-knots.[i-1])/(knots.[degree+i-1]-knots.[i-1])
              let Alpha2 =
                match ((knots.[i+degree]-knots.[i])=0.0) with
                |true-> 0.0
                |false -> (knots.[i+degree]-x)/(knots.[i+degree]-knots.[i])

              Alpha1*(basis x (degree-1) i knots) + Alpha2 * (basis x (degree-1) (i+1) knots)
B
```

Cheers,
Stig

The code I`m trying to replicate:

```
basis <- function(x, degree, i, knots) {
 if(degree == 0){
  B <- ifelse((x >= knots[i]) & (x < knots[i+1]), 1, 0)
  } 
  else {
   if((knots[degree+i] - knots[i]) == 0) {
      alpha1 <- 0
   } 
   else {
      alpha1 <- (x - knots[i])/(knots[degree+i] - knots[i])
   }
   if((knots[i+degree+1] - knots[i+1]) == 0) {
      alpha2 <- 0
   } else {
      alpha2 <- (knots[i+degree+1] - x)/(knots[i+degree+1] - knots[i+1])
   }
 B <- alpha1*basis(x, (degree-1), i, knots) + alpha2*basis(x, (degree-1), (i+1), knots)
 }
return(B)
}

bs <- function(x, degree=3, interior.knots=NULL, intercept=FALSE, Boundary.knots =              c(0,1)) {
if(missing(x)) stop("You must provide x")
if(degree < 1) stop("The spline degree must be at least 1")
   Boundary.knots <- sort(Boundary.knots)
   interior.knots.sorted <- NULL
if(!is.null(interior.knots)) interior.knots.sorted <- sort(interior.knots)
  knots <- c(rep(Boundary.knots[1], (degree+1)), interior.knots.sorted,rep(Boundary.knots[2], (degree+1)))
   K <- length(interior.knots) + degree + 1
   B.mat <- matrix(0,length(x),K)
for(j in 1:K) B.mat[,j] <- basis(x, degree, j, knots)
   if(any(x == Boundary.knots[2])) B.mat[x == Boundary.knots[2], K] <- 1
   if(intercept == FALSE) {
     return(B.mat[,-1])
   } else {
return(B.mat)
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call basis with multiple x's then I would do this:

1. First change the signature of basis to

   `let rec basis degree i (knots:float[]) (x:float)`
2. Call it for all the xs you want like this:

   `xs |> List.map (basis degree i knots)`

That should give you an array if all the other things work as expected. What that means is that I take all my x's and piping (|>) it to the function `List.map`. `List.map` takes a function and an list of elements and apply the function to all elements in the list and returns a new list where the function has been applied.